# How to call a function every Y amount of seconds, but Y changes depending on other events?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

```
InvokeRepeating("MoveEnemies", 1.0f, ratioAlive);
```

I called this in the start method. However, it will only run with the original `ratioAlive` value.

If I run it in the update, it runs every frame which I do not want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you literally need to call a function every N seconds (where N != const) and you cannot implement it via [events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/), then you can try using a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). 
It will call `Foo()` every N seconds automatically, but N may be changed in this class or another one:

```
public float Delay; // Your "N"

private IEnumerator InvokeRepeatedly () { // Coroutine that invokes the function
    while (true) {
        Foo(); // Call
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Delay);// Wait
    }
}

private void Foo () {...} // The function
```

You can also send some arguments:

```
private IEnumerator InvokeRepeatedly (int a, bool b) {
    while (true) {
        Foo(a, b);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Delay);
    }
}

private void Foo (int a, bool b) {...}
```

---

Moreover, you can define your own delegate (or use the existing) and call different functions via the Coroutine, unless their parameters or return value differ.

```
delegate void SomeDelegate(float a, bool b); // Defininf delegate type

private IEnumerator InvokeRepeatedly (SomeDelegate func, float a, bool b) {
    func(a, b); // Call function sent as an argument
}

private void Func1 (float num, bool isTrue) {...} // First fucntion
private void Func2 (float num, bool isTrue) {...} // Second function
// Whatever void function that takes these arguments would be appropriate.
```

If so, you can call it this way:

```
SomeDelegate func = new SomeDelegate(Func1); // Define a delegate instance
StartCoroutine(InvokeRepeatedly(func, 1.0f, true)); // Call coroutine that will call function
```